# How can I mount a large, heavy, half-inch-thick sign on a wall WITHOUT drilling through it?

Tags: mounting

I'm trying to mount a large sign - roughly 7.5 feet wide by 2.5 feet high - that's made of some kind of very hard plastic on a wall (drywall with wooden studs).

For a number of reasons, I don't want to drill through the sign. But it weighs roughly 60 lbs, so it can't be glued or anything: I clearly need to mount something else to the wall using screws in studs (or very strong drywall anchors).

Essentially, this makes the project a lot like hanging a frameless mirror - I need clips or clamps or something that can be sturdily mounted, that will hold this thing in place. But the mirror clips and j-mold stuff I've been able to find are all designed for thin, flat things (like a mirror). This sign is 1/2" thick.

What are my options? I'm open to corner holders, many metal clips around the perimeter, a j-mold-like solution, etc. Just can't involve putting holes through the sign itself.

(I did do a a fair bit of searching for dupes, but none of the excellent mounting posts I found seemed to address a situation like mine. If I overlooked one, point me at it, and apologies in advance.)

Comment: Exactly 1/2"?  What about : https://www.amazon.com/Impex-Systems-50233-Heavy-Mirror/dp/B00FL3RLCG  Plenty of options for mirror mount style clips like this.

Comment: @j... that's actually really in line with what I'm looking for, but I'm concerned it won't hold the weight?  They're rated for 20 pounds. Obviously, I'd use at least 4 on the bottom, but my understanding is that you cant just multiply (and assume 4 can hold 80 lbs)?

Comment: Sure, that would be fine.  Just make sure to anchor them well.  If you can't put them into studs then hefty E-Z anchors into drywall would be good (the bigger ones will hold 50lbs shear each).  Just make sure to line them up well so that you don't end up with all the load on just two.  You could even add 1/8" of foam tape to the bottom of the channel as a cushion and to help distribute the load over the clips (and give you some wiggle room in getting the alignment right).  No problem.

Comment: @NiallC. OP using lbs, no regard for the possibility of other units... quotes 1/2" for thickness, probably USA.  Profile says NY.  Infer US customary units.  Hanging on the wall, weight of 60lbs - reasonable natural unit is the foot for linear dimension.  Theorize - 7.5ft x 2.5ft x 1/2" = 0.78 cu.ft.  Implies density of 76.8 lb/cu.ft, or 1.23g/cm3.  Material is given as "hard plastic" - typical density of ~1g/cm3 for high molecular weight polymer.  Conclusion - feet are the probable unit with high confidence.

Comment: @j... you interested in combining your comments into an answer?  It's looking like my most likely solution to try out, so it might be for someone else in a similar spot in the future, too?

Comment: It's an amazon link - not sure that product recommendations are the right sort of thing, for here, to be honest.  Otherwise the answer is that the thing you already knew you wanted exists - just had to look a bit harder.

Comment: You just need a pair of anti-gravity levitating picture hanger clips.

Comment: Given the surface area to weight ratio (a measly 3.2lbs/sq.ft.), glue would probably work.  The wall would need to be thoroughly cleaned and you would need the glue to be spread evenly across the entire back of the sign, so something like the contact cement used for gluing down door skins and formica countertops would be a decent choice.  This does, of course, make removing the sign without destroying the drywall practically impossible though.

Answer (score 8):

By not excluding drilling into the wall, you may have more options at hand. The first configuration that comes to mind is a modification of the "hidden shelf" design.

Drilling a hole in the studs to take bolts forming a line to support the bottom of the sign would be similar to the hidden shelf construction. A piece of trim cut with a rabbet with the lip outboard of the sign will prevent it from slipping off.

A similar, but less hefty rabbet trim on the top will secure the sign from tipping.

For the weight you've noted, it would be best to have as many supports in the wall as possible. There will be a small overlap on the sign where the rabbet prevents fall-off, but even one-eighth of an inch (3 mm) would be sufficient if minimizing intrusion is important.

[image]

Comment: +1, since this is an elegant solution for some folks with similar needs. But in my personal situation I need something I can do without too much precision woodworking required?

Answer (score 5):

Use a french cleat: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_cleat

Attach the cleat to the wall side with toggles or screws into the wall, and attach the other side of the cleat with whatever fasteners or adhesives are appropriate for the type of plastic that the sign is made out of.

Comment: This is the best solution IMHO. The cleat can be long enough to be secured into 5 studs ( if they are 16 on center ).  if you have a table saw ( or a friend with one ) you can make one out of  1"x4" lumber by ripping it in half with the blade set to the steepest angle you can set your saw to. This will give you the two matching half's to your cleat.  You will need a two pieces of scrap  of the same thickens as your cleat to attach to the bottom of the sigh to keep it sitting parallel to the wall. You could put a strip of LED lights around the perimeter on the back side for a cool effect.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just purchase a ready made shelf, install it on the wall, and let your sign sit on it.  If the shelf mounts are attached to the studs, it should easily support the weight.